# Can colors be included in strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, color

Colors are displayed in output like squares of the corresponding color. Say, if input is `Blue`, the output will be a blue square.

I would like to use this in a string and I don't know how to do it. If my input is `"x("<>Blue<>")"` this produces an error. What I would like to achieve is the output looking like x(*) where * denotes a blue square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html).

```
Row[{"x(", Blue, ")"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

In a notebook you can generally put *anything* in a string just by pasting it while typing a string:

[image]

Comment: Oh my this is even better! Except that I cannot figure out how to do it "blindly". I mean, if I need something like `stupidf[color_]:=Row[{"f(",color,")"}]`...

Comment: Constructing these strings, I think they are called linear syntax, by hand is not advised.  Maybe `ToString[Row[{"f(", color, ")"}], StandardForm]` will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
Row[{"x(", RGBColor[Blue], ")"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will accept another one, only because the solution is slightly shorter, sorry...

Comment: No problem - my `RGBColor` is indeed redundant

Comment: It's redundant but shows how to use any color that isn't built-in.